# Test Paypal Subscription

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm attempting to develop a PayPal subscription using the REST API, and while working on the implementation, I've encountered several issues. One of the challenges I've faced is figuring out how to test the subscription functionality without having to wait for a full day to pass.
In the PayPal sandbox environment, is there a feature similar to the clock simulation in Stripe that allows me to accelerate the testing process for subscription intervals? This would greatly assist in expediting the testing and development of the subscription system.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the status of a paypal subscription using node like this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const clientIdAndSecret = "CLIENTID:SECRET";

async function verifySubscription(subscriptionID) { 
   const authUrl = "https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
   const subscriptionsUrl = "https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subscriptionID;

  //sandbox urls
  //const authUrl = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
  //const subscriptionsUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/" + subscriptionID;

   const base64 = Buffer.from(clientIdAndSecret).toString('base64');
   try {
      let response = await fetch(authUrl, { 
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            'Authorization': `Basic ${base64}`,
         },
         body: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
       });
     let data = await response.json();
     let subResponse = await fetch(subscriptionsUrl, { 
        method: 'get', 
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+data.access_token, 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }, 
    });
    let subscriptionData = await subResponse.json();
    if (!!subscriptionData) {
        if (subscriptionData.status === "ACTIVE") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont need the status of subscription, but how to test a billing cycle without waiting day,week,month,year for each billing cycle

Comment: If you dissect the return data from the subscription request you can find their last payment date and amount